Metatags for shopify
I'm currently working on a project where I need to fetch and display metaobjects from a specific folder in Shopify using Liquid. The folder is named "Johnson Controls" under the "Connections" metaobjects.
Despite my efforts, the metaobjects are not being displayed correctly on the page. I've included debug statements to verify the fetched metaobjects, but it still doesn't seem to work.
Here is the code I'm using:
<div class="mentor-container">
    {% assign connection_name = 'connections' %}
    {% assign metaobjects = shop.metaobjects[connection_name] %}

    <h2>Debug Information</h2>
    <ul>
    {% for metaobject in metaobjects %}
      <li>
        Name: {{ metaobject.name }}
        <ul>
          {% for field in metaobject %}
            <li>{{ field[0] }}: {{ field[1] }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    {% assign filtered_metaobjects = metaobjects | where: 'company', 'Johnson Controls' %}

    {% if filtered_metaobjects.size > 0 %}
      <meta name="description" content="{{ filtered_metaobjects.first.description | escape }}">
      {% render 'meta-tags' %}
    {% else %}
      <p>No metaobjects found for the specified company.</p>
    {% endif %}

    {% for metaobject in filtered_metaobjects %}
      <div class="mentor-card" onclick="openVideo('{{ metaobject.vimeo_1.value }}')">
        {% if metaobject.photo.value %}
          <img src="{{ metaobject.photo.value | image_url: width: 100 }}" alt="{{ metaobject.name.value }}">
        {% else %}
          <p>No photo available for {{ metaobject.name.value }}</p>
        {% endif %}
        {% if metaobject.name.value %}
          <h3>{{ metaobject.name.value }}</h3>
        {% endif %}
        {% if metaobject.job.value %}
          <p>{{ metaobject.job.value }}</p>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>


What output are you getting by doing this?
Make sure the metaobject is visible to your storefront.
You should have no problem accessing the entries of this metaobject as long as you have correctly specified the definitions and entries to them.
When you mention that you have a folder do you mean a metaobject definition?
Please provide some more detail to better understand the issue.

Im trying to show the contents of the entire folder.  the folder is in content - metaobjects - connections - johnsons controls. can you help me out?
